# Scraping - character encoding

Tags: php, character-encoding, scraper

I'm scraping some data from large tables on the web to populate a database.  Some of the characters show up fine on my screen but do stuff like this when I scrape: `!¬†√Öland Islands`

I'm using file_get_contents to grab the raw data.  It looks fine after I've scraped it (ie if I just var_dump the raw result): `Åland Islands`

I then turn the data into an array and write it to a text file or sql file.  What do I need to do to preserve the character formatting?

Comment: I think you should start with [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/). Your question may answer itself afterwards.

Comment: Deceze - this gave me a total understanding of character encoding.  Thank you.  Do you accept donations?

Comment: Glad it helped! If you really feel like giving me something for it, contact me privately (see end of the article). But I'm not really set up for donations, a postcard or so will have to do. :o)

Answer (score 1):

When “Å” is turned to “!¬†√Ö” (five characters), then it is most probably a consequence of two or more incorrect character code conversions. A single incorrect conversion tends to turn a character to a different character, or to some pair or maybe triplet of characters, but hardly five characters.

If things look OK after scraping when you dump it, then you need to find out which character encoding is in use and check how you are writing the data to a file. If the data is UTF-8 encoded, as I suspect (a compilation of geographic names around the world more or less needs to be), then the writing operation should be one that operates on UTF-8 data, and when inspecting the result written to a file, the inspecting software should read the data as UTF-8 encoded, too.